# Align table headers to the rows

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create table with **fixed row headers** (so during scrolling the column heading stay) , I have been able to achieve that **but now the table headers are not aligned** to the rows below. I have also created a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PmmPJ/) for that. 
Currently the output is like:

[image]

Here is the sample extracted HTML.

```
<head>
    <style>
        table
        {
            /*background-color: #aaa;*/
            width: 800px;
        }
        tbody
        {
            /*background-color: #ddd;*/
            height: 200px;
            width: 800px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        td
        {
        }

        thead > tr, tbody
        {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
   <body>
    <div id="containerdiv" style="width: 800px">
        <table id="dynamictable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Title
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Media Title
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Broadcast Time
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Destination
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Channel
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Start Time
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        End Time
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tablebody">
                <tr id="0">
                    <td>
                        ID: 0
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some Content
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="1">
                    <td >
                        ID: 1
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some Content
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="Tr1">
                    <td>
                        ID: 1
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some Content
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: if you are using jquery try using http://www.fixedheadertable.com/

Comment: Well, for starters, if you insist on using inline CSS, you can assign the same width to the headers as you have the cells below.

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to use fixed width columns. Put a unique `class` on each column type and assign it a width in CSS.

Comment: @sbeliv01, I have tried removing width as well, so ass assigning a fixed width, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="containerdiv" style="width: 800px">
        <table id="dynamictable">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 100px">
                        ID
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 300px">
                        Title
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 300px">
                        Media Title
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Broadcast Time
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Destination
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Channel
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Start Time
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        End time
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="scroll">
        <table id="tablebody">
                <tr id="0">
                    <td style="width: 100px">
                        ID: 0
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 300px">
                        Some Content
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 300px">
                        Some more contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="1">
                    <td style="width: 100px">
                        ID: 1
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 300px">
                        Some Content
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 300px">
                        Some more contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="Tr1">
                    <td style="width: 100px">
                        ID: 1
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 300px">
                        Some Content
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 300px">
                        Some more contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some more contents contents contents
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
 table
        {
            /*background-color: #aaa;*/
            width: 780px;
        }

.scroll {
    height: 200px;
    width: 800px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#dynamictable {
     font-weight: bold;   
}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zyjSf/4/

Comment: +1, I like your idea of having two tables and a scrollable div. Also if you set the width of td and th same it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I modified my code to have fixed width columns for both header and table rows, but since now they are in two different tables, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Do NOT set `thead > tr, tbody` to display:block.  It should work if you remove that line.

By default, `<tbody>` has `display:table-row-group` and `<tr>` has `display:table-row`. You want to keep it as those defaults.

Comment: is right. You are forcing a TR and the TBODY to display 'block' style. The table rendering engine wont behave properly.

Comment: but it will not stop having the fixed column headers, If I scroll in the table, I will loose the column headers on top

Comment: oh, oops - my fault - I did not see the scrollbar in your fiddle because it was cut off on my screen.  I see what you mean.  Let me fix.

Comment: It looks like you would need JS for this unless you set fixed widths for the table cells.  I'd recommend JS over fixed widths, definitely.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to set a width for both `td` and `th`. Otherwise the table layout engine snags.

EDIT: Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zyjSf/3/).